# JQuery and script caching

Tags: jquery, caching

I'm experiencing a rather bizarre behaviour in JQuery.

I'm dynamically loading a series of scripts using this code:

```
for (var i=0; i<requiredScripts.length; i++)
    {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL+"js/"+requiredScripts[i],
        async: false,
        dataType: 'script',
        success: checkLoaded
        });
    }
```

The `checkLoaded` function just increments a counter, so that when all of the scripts have been loaded it executes certain functions.

Everything was working fine until I uploaded a newer version of one of the loaded scripts. JQuery seems to continue loading the old one. I tried refreshing (and force refreshing) the page in vain...

So I disabled the cache (from the WebDeveloper toolbar) and now the script magically loads.
But when I reenabled the cache the old script came back...

I went as far as deleting the file from the server, and that did not do anything! (unless I disable the cache, that is).

I'm sure I'm just missing something really simple, but I could not figure it out.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

**EDIT**: just to clarify, I do want the file to be cached. What I don't understand is why a force refresh of the page does not result in getting the new script.

Also, note that this only happens if I load the files with JQuery, if I add them manually in the HTML a force refresh loads the new page.

**EDIT #2**: solved by deleting the cache from FF. Still, don't understand why a CTRL+SHIFT+R did not do the trick...

Comment: what script do you see when you view the src in firebug?

Comment: @matpol: I always see the old one loaded.

Comment: ...unless I disable caching of course... but when I reenable the cache I see the old one back

Comment: what happens if you move the file somewhere else? does it still show in the src?

Comment: @matpol: yes, even if I delete it...

Answer (score 2):

$.ajax has a cache option that does the same thing as mck89's answer but is a little neater:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'example.com',
    cache : false,
    ....
});
```

Comment: This obviously work, but it is not what I need. I updated my question so that it is more clear: why can't I "overwrite" the file in cache with a force refresh of the page?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the classic caching disabling method.

```
var cd=+new Date();
for (var i=0; i<requiredScripts.length; i++)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseURL+"js/"+requiredScripts[i]+"?"+cd,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'script',
            success: checkLoaded
            });
    }
```

In this way the script url is always different and you are sure that its content is not cached.

Comment: apparently this isn't such a good idea:
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-fix-for-caching-updated-files.html

Comment: @matpol: it's not a good idea to use query strings when you want the file to be cached.  What's desired here is the opposite, so this isn't a bad idea.

Comment: it doesn't always work though and its a work around not a fix - as it won't actually fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tell apache to sent no-cache headers for your JS files:

```
<Directory "/path/to/baseURL/js">
    Header Set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-store"
</Directory>
```

Comment: Looks like bad karma to me. Caching is a good thing in general. OP should really go with adding a timestamp or even better, a release version to his `script files querystring`.