# Jquery code don't work in IE8. What to do?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm writing a web-application for the first time. Everything was tested in Chrome. And now i begin testing in IE8 too and found that my application have problems with positioning and jquery script.
Here is a problem: when i change something in css (for example positioning), my web page in IE8 isn't change. I pushed refresh button more than 10 times. What is it? (i checked - all files i uploaded to server).
here is my css: http://www.abcpatent.com/software/css_style.css

Next: I use buttons to move through the master in my application. From 1 point this buttons refuses to work and fonts become standard.Here is my jquery code: http://www.abcpatent.com/software/script.js

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's almost impossible to deduct an error from a Javascript source file. Also, you are very likely getting error messages in IE8. Please look for errors, and if there are any, post the code causing them.

Comment: I can't wait to fix your web site for you!

Comment: Could you provide us with the actual script page? Or at least the errors that IE8 gives you?

Comment: IE8 don't give me any errors. When i click "utility patent transmittal form" (the 11th menu option) menu, the below buttons don't work. However, when i click those buttons before 11 menu option everything is working, after - fonts is changing and buttons don't work.

    $('#next_step_button').click(function(){

        $(next_step).click();

    });

    $('#previous_step_button').click(function(){

        $(previous_step).click();

    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing IE cache. I had a similar problem (with FF).
Didn't really find the cause, and it doesn't seem to be really highly reproducible (happens with some scripts and not with others...)

Anyway, look here
[JQuery and script caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421717/jquery-and-script-caching)

Answer (score 1):

Hitting the refresh button reloads the page, resetting everything that has been changed by any javascript.

Make sure your objects are positioned properly. The default is *position:static* (CSS). As far as I know in that mode position properties don't work. You have to use fixed, absolute or relative.

Here's what I'd do:

- Check if the Javascript doesn't contain any errors.
- Check your HTML / CSS

Comment: thanks for the reply. Seems to be my ie8 is bugged. On another computer on every page refresh everything is changing

Comment: Ok, this is going to sound awfull, but..
Have you rebooted your computer yet?

Might be a problem with your IE8 cache or something.
I've had similar problems with all browsers, and for windows a reboot sometimes fixes it

Answer (score 0):

On your IE browser window, look at the bottom left corner of the browser. Do you see a yellow triangle? If so, click that yellow triangle and see what the error message is.

Comment: There is no yellow triangle :(